# Disable hover property for element in SASS

Tags: css, sass

Suppose we had:

```
.a {

    /** Some properties here **/

    .b {
        /* Some properties here **/
    }

    &:hover {
        .b {
            /* change b here */
        }
    }
}
```

And there's an element `<div class = "b">`, is there a way to prevent the hover property from being applied to this div?

I tried:

```
.a {

    /** Some properties here **/

    .b {
        /* Some properties here **/
    }

    .c {
        /* empty */
    }

    &:hover {
        .b:not(.c) {
            /* change b here */
        }
    }
}
```

And I also set the class to be `<div class = "b c">`.

Any help would be appreciated this scss file is shared by other files so I don't want to change it too much.

Answer (score 0):

> Suppose I only want to apply it to div with the class b but not b and c. How would I do that?

This should do it, assuming all the elements you would wish for the hover effect to apply to are `div` elements:

```
&:hover {
    div:not([class*='b c']) {
      /* stuff here */
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that the order of the classes is important, so class `c` must come immediately after class `b`.

**[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aNMPBo)**

Read about what each selector does [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/).

Comment: suppose I only want to apply it to div with the class b but not b and c. How would I do that?